# Google Drive API: what fields can we use for the fields mask?

Tags: google-drive-api

I know that we can customize our results from requests like [Files.copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy) and [Files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert), but is there a list of the field names we can use?

Answer (score 0):

The only place I could find it was in the ["Try it!" editor](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy#try-it) of the Google Drive Api reference. Here is the extremely long, unadulterated list

note: i believe that if you want to reference a child field, like `aperture` under `imageMediaMetadata`, you would use a backslash: `"imageMediaMetadata/aperture"`

```
alternateLink
appDataContents
copyable
createdDate
defaultOpenWithLink
description
downloadUrl
editable
embedLink
etag
explicitlyTrashed
exportLinks
fileExtension
fileSize
headRevisionId
iconLink
id
imageMediaMetadata
    aperture
    cameraMake
    cameraModel
    colorSpace
    date
    exposureBias
    exposureMode
    exposureTime
    flashUsed
    focalLength
    height
    isoSpeed
    lens
    location
        altitude
        latitude
        longitude
    maxApertureValue
    meteringMode
    rotation
    sensor
    subjectDistance
    whiteBalance
    width
indexableText
    text
kind
labels
    hidden
    restricted
    starred
    trashed
    viewed
lastModifyingUser
lastModifyingUserName
lastViewedByMeDate
markedViewedByMeDate
md5Checksum
mimeType
modifiedByMeDate
modifiedDate
openWithLinks
originalFilename
ownerNames
owners
    displayName
    emailAddress
    isAuthenticatedUser
    kind
    permissionId
    picture
        url
parents
    id
    isRoot
    kind
    parentLink
    selfLink
permissions
    additionalRoles
    authKey
    domain
    emailAddress
    etag
    id
    kind
    name
    photoLink
    role
    selfLink
    type
    value
    withLink
properties
    etag
    key
    kind
    selfLink
    value
    visibility
quotaBytesUsed
selfLink
shared
sharedWithMeDate
sharingUser
thumbnail
    image
    mimeType
thumbnailLink
title
userPermission
version
webContentLink
webViewLink
writersCanShare
```